# Fatal error: Class 'Vlabs\MediaBundle\VlabsMediaBundle' not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, composer-php

I'm trying to install [VlabsMediaBundle](https://github.com/V-labs/VlabsMediaBundle) to use it in my Symfony App I've followed the [installation instruction](https://github.com/V-labs/VlabsMediaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-bundle-setup-and-usage.md) step by step by adding these to `composer.json` :

composer.json

```
{
    require: {
        "vlabs/media-bundle": ">=1.1"
    }
}
```

AppKernel.php

```
<?php

$bundles = array(
    new Vlabs\MediaBundle\VlabsMediaBundle(),
);
```

now when I run `composer.phar install` in the console I get this fatal ERROR :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Vlabs\MediaBundle\VlabsMediaBundle' not found in C:\Users\TH
INK\Desktop\PHP-Symfony2---Build_a_CMS-master\app\AppKernel.php on line 18
```

what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You should perform the `composer install` before you add the class to your kernel.

Comment: the same error ! do I need to clone the github repo VlabsMediaBundle in my project ?